# Python weird ModuleNotFoundError at wrong position in code

Tags: python, numpy, import, modulenotfounderror

I am having a super weird error, the situation is the following:
I am writing some code in a package called hsltools. The Module is called em_combiner1_4. I recently changed the version from 1_3, and also changed all imports accordingly.
If I run my code now, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\git_home\hsltools\hsltools\tests\emc_tester\EMC_tester.py", line 85, in <module>
    combine_2d()
  File "C:\Users\...\git_home\hsltools\hsltools\tests\emc_tester\EMC_tester.py", line 48, in combine_2d
    elec_field2d = emc.EM(import_path+"2DelecMap.ef2.npz")
  File "c:\users\...\git_home\hsltools\hsltools\em_combiner1_4.py", line 441, in __init__
    load_npz()
  File "c:\users\...\git_home\hsltools\hsltools\em_combiner1_4.py", line 251, in load_npz
    self.em_type = data["metadata"][1]
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 254, in __getitem__
    return format.read_array(bytes,
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 744, in read_array
    array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hsltools.em_combiner1_3
```

The thing I don't get is the location of the error: `...\numpy\lib\format.py`.
There is absolutaly no import there, and anyway, numpy would not import my module.
I am wondering if I am generally misunderstanding some basic concept, or if the error is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening while deserializing pickled objects. Pickle stores the type information including the module name. When loading a pickled object, the module is imported to construct the final object.

Your pickle file contains an object that is part of `hsltools.em_combiner1_3`. So that is the module pickle tries to find.

Comment: Thanks! 
Do you have any Idea how to avoid this happening? 
Interesting is also, that this never happend between version 1_1 -> 1_2 -> 1_3.

Comment: @Jonathanthesailor Well, what do you want to happen? Sounds like you are the developer of these modules. You changed their name, presumably to indicate that they are no longer backwards compatible (otherwise you could have simply changed the ```__version__``` field, see https://peps.python.org/pep-0396/). How do you want to load objects of an old, potentially incompatible type into a new type?

Comment: Ah ok. I didn't know about __version__. I am indeed developing this module, and have just been changing the name of the module, in order to change the version. The old .npz files are exactly the same as the new ones (they just save a np array, a boolean and a dictionary). These files are compatible with all versions.